# How to create pop up window while upgrading new version of the application using installshield

Tags: windows-installer, upgrade, installshield-le

I am using InstallShield as my Windows installer. I am doing minor upgrade to every new release of my application, upgrade works correctly. But I want to show like one pop up window about informing the upgrade. How can I create window like that before upgrade starts?

Is there any way to show by using InstallShield or patch or code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a VBScript custom action that displays a [message box](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.messagebox(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1). If running a silent install is important to your install requirements you would of course want to prepare for this if you put it in your installExecuteSequence. In the condition attribute just put in logic that evaluates to true when upgrading.

Since you're using InstallShield you could also do something similar with InstallScript, but that does create a dependency on their InstallScript engine if you're not already using InstallScript actions.

For simple things like an upgrading popup I like to use VBScript since they're quick to code for.

Comment: Thanks for your response... Unfortunately InstallShield Limited edition doesn't allow to use scripts.

Comment: The only thing it doesn't allow script-wise is InstallScript. You can still author VBScript actions. You can also write C++ or C# actions but that would be overkill for your needs.

Note this page is from MSDN and not Flexera (InstallShield)
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa371538(v=vs.85).aspx